# what did sudo passwd do

Tags: security

I was trying to change the default password for my raspberry pi and I used `sudo passwd` instead of just `passwd`. What did I change when I used `sudo passwd`?

It didn't even ask me to enter the current password. It just asked me to enter a new password and confirm it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using sudo you are executing the command as root. So, in this case you changed the password for the root account.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` provide you the `root` access, it executes command as `root`. So using **`sudo passwd`** command you can reset/change the root password on any Linux based operating system. There is no direct security risk.

You can use it as following:

`$ sudo passwd <your username>`